# make a border override max-width

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a body and navbar with a `max-width: 1200px;`. The navbar has a `border-top: 1em solid blue;`. The navbar itself disappears when scrolling down and reappears when scrolling up. I've just been asked to make the top border extend to full viewport width, thus overriding the `max-width: 1200px;` of its containing div. If I add a top border to the body and adjust the navbar padding to not cover the top navbar, when scrolling up there is a gap due to the added padding. The site is already live and I don't want to break all the other styling. Is there a way to extend the top-border of a navbar without having to change anything else?

Comment: Have you considered using a pseudo-element, on the parent element, and setting that to fullwidth, displaying it `block` and declaring a `min-height`? Try embedding a stack code snippet (see formatting options) with the mark-up and styles you're currently using.

Comment: It's helpful to provide some sort of functioning snippet so we can try to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Bottom line - your parent element has `max-width` and you want the child be wider. You can achieve that with declaring `overflow:visible` on the parent and giving the child `100vw` width. Also you can have the child as `position:absolute` and just take it out of the parent element (that is what I suggest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Hungerstar a pseudo-element is optimal here.

I prefer a CSS3 solution involving a 100vw width pseudo-element which is then translated back with a `transform`.

This eliminates the need for the `overflow` on the body.

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed #6DA76D;
}
header:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  
  transform:translate(-50%,-100%);
  width:100vw;

  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Nav One</li>
      <li>Nav Two</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I always forget about `translate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo element and stretch it outside of the parent element.

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Nav One</li>
      <li>Nav Two</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed #6DA76D;
}
header:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -99em;
  left: -99em;
  border-top: 5px solid skyblue;
}
```

Here we absolute position the pseudo element to the parent element. We pull it outside of the parent by applying negative margins. Those negative margins are pretty large and will cause an horizontal scrollbar. You'll have to use `overflow: hidden;` to get rid of it. I did this on the `<body>` in my example.

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yubr42wk/).